# Nesting LINQ to XML retrieval

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, .net-core

I have an XML file with the following structure...

```
<Tournament TeamPlayers="1">
    <Teams>
        <Team>
            <TeamID></TeamID>
            <Name></Name>
            <Status></Status>
            <Memo></Memo>
            <ByeRounds></ByeRounds>
            <Players>
                <Player Seat="A">
                    <MemberNo></MemberNo>
                    <MemberName></MemberName>
                    <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
                    <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
                </Player>
            </Players>
        </Team>
    </Teams>
    <Staff>
        <Player>
            <MembershipNo></MembershipNo>
            <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
            <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
            <MembershipName></MembershipName>
            <Position></Position>
        </Player>
    </Staff>
    
    <Penalties>
        <Penalty>
            <Judge></Judge>
            <Player></Player>
            <InfractionType></InfractionType>
            <PenaltyType></PenaltyType>
            <Notes></Notes>
        </Penalty>
    </Penalties>
</Tournament>
```

The idea is that I would iterate through each child node (`Teams`, `Staff`, `Penalty`) and assign each into a list. I have the following bit of code to start but can't figure out how to go into the nested `Players` element and assign it to `.tpPlayerA` as part of the `New PlayerInfo` construct.

```
    Dim TeamsNodes = xDoc.Descendants("Teams")

        lstOutputTeams = team.Descendants("Team").[Select](Function(t) New TournamentTeam With {
                                              .intTeamID = t.Element("TeamID"),
                                              .intByeRounds = t.Element("ByeRounds"),
                                              .strTeamName = t.Element("Name"),
                                              .strMemo = t.Element("Memo"),
                                              .intStatus = t.Element("Status"),
                                              .tpPlayerA = (From p In team.Descendants("Players") Select New PlayerInfo With {
                                                        .strMembershipNo = p.Element("MemberNo").Value,
                                                        .strPlayerFirstName = p.Element("PlayerFirstName").Value,
                                                        .strPlayerLastName = p.Element("PlayerLastName").Value,
                                                        .strMembershipName = p.Element("MemberName")})
                                            }).ToList()
    Next

    lstFinalOutput.Add(lstOutputTeams)
```

(The above kind of ported from this answer: [Nesting LINQ to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670442/nesting-linq-to-xml) )

However running the above,I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format". What did I get wrong here?

Comment: Do not use value which gives error when null.  Instead use code like this From : p.Element("PlayerFirstName").Value  To :  (string)p.Element("PlayerFirstName")

Comment: It looks like a bug, but can't understand where.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm missing something... but,

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'to load from file
    'xe = XElement.Load("path")

    ' testing use literal
    xe = <Tournament TeamPlayers="1">
             <Teams>
                 <Team>
                     <TeamID></TeamID>
                     <Name></Name>
                     <Status></Status>
                     <Memo></Memo>
                     <ByeRounds></ByeRounds>
                     <Players>
                         <Player Seat="A">
                             <MemberNo></MemberNo>
                             <MemberName></MemberName>
                             <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
                             <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
                         </Player>
                     </Players>
                 </Team>
             </Teams>
             <Penalties>
                 <Penalty>
                     <Judge></Judge>
                     <Player></Player>
                     <InfractionType></InfractionType>
                     <PenaltyType></PenaltyType>
                     <Notes></Notes>
                 </Penalty>
             </Penalties>
             <Staff>
                 <Player>
                     <MembershipNo></MembershipNo>
                     <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
                     <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
                     <MembershipName></MembershipName>
                     <Position></Position>
                 </Player>
             </Staff>
         </Tournament>

    Dim staff As List(Of XElement)
    Dim teams As List(Of XElement)
    Dim penalties As List(Of XElement)

    staff = (From el In xe.<Staff>.<Player>
              Select el).ToList

    teams = (From el In xe.<Teams>.<Team>
              Select el).ToList

    penalties = (From el In xe.<Penalties>.<Penalty>
                  Select el).ToList
```